# Normalization to 2NF and 3NF

Tags: database-design, normalization, database-theory

I solved this example to determine 2NF and 3NF. I would like to check if my answer is correct. Can somebody check the 2NF and 3NF of this example, please?

```
R( A B C D E F G H I J)
```

with functional dependencies:

```
AB -> C
A -> DE
B -> F
F -> GH
D -> IJ
```

My result:

```
2NF: 
R1 (AB -> C , A -> E) 
R2 (B -> F , F -> GH)
R3 (D -> I)

3NF:
R1 (AB -> C , A -> E) 
R2 (B -> F) 
R4 (F -> GH)
R3 (D -> I)
```

Comment: Hi @chris if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, i suggest you the steps to quickly find a correct normalization of the table, using the example that you brought, showing you the correct normalization.

### Define the key

The key is usually defined by its usefulness, or its role in operations like joins (if we need a join lot of times we could choose a key instead of another).

I choose `A U B` as a key. I usually underline the key, but, because in this board we can't underline text, I will write the key as **`AB`**

### Define the functional dependencies

You already found the FD, so we can go to the next step.

### 2NF Normalization

Looking at the FD the correct normalization is:

```
R1 (the previous big table) (**A**:R3,**B**:R2, C)
  AB -> C
```

(`:R2` indicates a foreign key)

In this table we can find the `AB -> C` functional dependency.

```
R2 (**B**,F, G, H) 
  B -> F, 
  F -> GH

R3 (**A**, D, E, I, J) 
  A -> DE, 
  D -> IJ
```

### 3NF Normalization

```
R1 (**A**:R3, **B**:R2, C) 
  AB -> C

R2 (**B**, F:R4) 
  B -> F

R3 (**A**, D:R5, E) 
  A -> DE

R4 (**F**, G, H) 
  F -> GH

R5 (**D**, I, J) 
  D -> IJ
```

Comment: I've edited yopur answer, mainly the format. I agree on the results (2nf and 3nf) but I disagree that there is any choice in the original table. The only candidate key is `AB`. +1 none the less.